# Zero or one to many relation in Access

Tags: ms-access, foreign-key-relationship

I working on a project in Access and having a problem with a relations.
Assume that I have a table named "Phone Numbers" with has primary key - "numbers" and another field - "Identification Number". this field is connected by one to many relations to two other tables: "Contacts" and "Applicators". Both tables has primary key "Identification Number".
When I try to add some entities in "Phone Numbers", Access pops up an error message saying that I must have entities in both tables with the "Identification Number" equals to the one in "Phone Numbers". The problem is that Contact and Applicators not necessarily the same person.
I need a way to tell Access that each "Phone Numbers" entity is related to either "Contacts" or "Applicators", but not both.
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the relations. You have to tell access, that a relation can be null. Go to the relationships, right-click on the relations, choose manage relation... (sorry I have the german version - probably the menu is called differently, but I hope you get the gist...) in the popup window choose relationtype... in the next window chose "All data from PhoneNumbers and only those from Contacts where the content of the connected fields have the same value